# Is there a canonical way to convert a keyword to a symbol with no :?

Tags: symbols, keywords

I want to convert keywords, e.g. :some-key to a plain symbol like some-key. I currently do this with:

```
(intern-soft (substring (symbol-name :some-key) 1))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Perhaps it could be avoided altogether? (Fwiw I don't know of a better way)

Comment: You already show a trivial way to do what you want. What do you have in mind wrt a "canonical" way, and why? Is there [some other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821) hiding here, or is this the question, to which the answer is just "no"?

Comment: The answer could be no. It seems like there might be a built-in function I wasn't aware of.

Comment: There is no other question. I was doing this to convert a plist to the body of a let inside a macro.